# Listing folder in /Users

Tags: applescript

Using Applescript, I have been able to successfully list the folders on my desktop as a selection using this code:

```
set the_folder to (path to desktop)
tell application "Finder"
set foldernames to name of every folder of entire contents of the_folder
end tell
set theChosenOne to choose from list folder names
```

However, when I attempt to do the same for the /Users folder:

```
set Users to "/Users"
set the_folder to Users
tell application "Finder"
set foldernames to name of every folder of entire contents of the_folder
end tell
set theChosenOne to choose from list foldernames
```

It returns this error: error "Can’t get entire contents of \"/Users\"." number -1728 from «class ects» of "/Users"

Searched on that error, but not finding much info.  Thanks for any help you can give me with this one.

Comment: You may have some luck using `do shell script` with `find /Users -maxdepth 1 -type d` Maybe try it in Terminal first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because the Finder does not support slash separated POSIX paths.

But there is a simpler solution. `path to users folder` return an `alias` reference to the folder `/Users` which can be used directly.

```
set the_folder to path to users folder
tell application "Finder"
    set foldernames to name of every folder of entire contents of the_folder
end tell
set theChosenOne to choose from list foldernames
```

**Caveat**: Be aware that `entire contents` is very slow. After 2 minutes you will get an *Apple Event timed out* error. You might wrap the `Finder` tell block in a `with timeout` block. However I'd recommend `find` or `mdfind` of the shell which are incredibly much faster. And most likely you will get also an *access privileges violation* error.

Comment: That did it, thanks!  Error at first, but added the parenthesis to the first line and it worked.  You're right about 'entire contents' and in this case didn't need them so removed that and, yes, it ran much faster.  Thanks again!